# Post Request and WebkitBoundary

Tags: python, request, webkit

i hope you having a nice day.

I want to use python request to submit a form. The website I want to send the form use Contact Form 7 from Wordpress.

And when I check the value I need to send I see this :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryTS7bVTlHoJAHKQQk

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_wpcf7" 880

------WebKitFormBoundaryTS7bVTlHoJAHKQQk Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_wpcf7_version"

4.9.2

------WebKitFormBoundaryTS7bVTlHoJAHKQQk Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_wpcfy_locale"

[]
```

and when I check the Request Header using the Debug Tool I see this line as well :

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryTS7bVTlHoJAHKQQk
```

What is the TS7bVT1HoJAHKQQk ? Do I need to generate a variable like that to submit properly the form ? If Yes how can I generate onec.

When I submit my form using request I do receive a confirmation in the json saying mail_sent so I was wondering since I never received a call nor a email back (it's for job finding purpose)is it because I didn't implement the WebkitFormBoundary... ?

Cheers and thank you in advance for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it

Edit : Here's my code

```
session = requests.session()
payload = {
        "your-tel" : phone_number ,
        "your-name" : last ,
        "your-firstname" : first ,
        "your-email" : mail[p].strip().split(':')[0] ,
        "lang" : "fr" ,
        "g-recaptcha-response" : recaptcha_answer ,
        "bb2_screener_" : "1529168805 83.227.72.84 83.227.72.84" ,
        "accept" : "1" ,
        "_wpcf7cf_visible_groups" : "[]" ,
        "_wpcf7cf_options" : '{"form_id":880,"conditions":[],"settings":false}' ,
        "_wpcf7cf_hidden_groups" : "[]" ,
        "_wpcf7cf_hidden_group_fields" : "[]" ,
        "_wpcf7_version" : "4.9.2" ,
        "_wpcf7_unit_tag" : "wpcf7-f880-p881-o1" ,
        "_wpcf7_locale" : "fr_FR" ,
        "_wpcf7_container_post" : "881" ,
        "_wpcf7" : "880" ,
    }

header = {

        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'fr',
        "Connection":"keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1",
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/65.0.3325.181 Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }





submit = session.post('website', data=payload, headers=header, timeout=120)
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Oh yeah the most important part. I edited my post